# Fastest way to get MySQL cell data as a string?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I want to take the value of a single MySQL cell and use it as a string inside PHP code - I already know the cell exists, where it is, and nothing else is needed. What's the easiest way to do this? All the examples I've found focus on using a loop to output multiple rows into a table, which seems needlessly complicated for my purposes.

Basically what I want to do is this:

```
require_once 'login.php'; // Connects to MySQL
$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='1'"; // id is determined elsewhere
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

echo "Your name is " . $result;
```

But I get an error message that it's not a valid string.

Comment: `echo "Your name is " . mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['name'];`  that is not the best practice, but if you are sure that you have non empty result :)

Comment: What @alex said.  The reason you're having a problem right now is `mysqli_query()` returns a result object.  And `echo` only accepts strings.  Can't echo an object unless it's implemented the magic method `__toString()`

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to fetch record from `$result` using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

So you can fix your code this way:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "Your name is " . $row['name'];
}
```